# SQL Select a specific value in the group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this following table

```
Dept----------  Sub_Dept----      Dept Type    
Sales.............Advertising........A    
Sales.............Marketing......... B    
Sales.............Analytics.......... C
Operations.....IT..................... C    
Operations.....Settlement........C
```

And the result should be if a department got a department type as A then change all record of that department to A, else keep it same

```
Dept----------  Sub_Dept----      Dept Type    
Sales.............Advertising........A   
Sales.............Marketing......... A    
Sales.............Analytics.......... A    
Operations.....IT..................... C    
Operations.....Settlement........C
```

Anybody can give a suggestion on this? I thought of using the GROUP BY but have to output the Sub Department as well

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd write a subquery to return each distinct department that has a dept type of A, then use that to change all records returned that have a dept in the subquery to dept type of A, otherwise leave them alone.

Comment: Do you want an `update` or a `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query

```
select a11.dept, a12.Sub_Dept, (case when a12.min_dep_type='A' then 'A' else a11.dep_type) as dep_type
from tab a11
JOIN (select dept, min(dep_type) min_dep_type from tab group by dept) a12
on a11.dept = a12.dept
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
update t
    set depttype = 'a'
    where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.dept = 'a') and
          t.dept <> 'a';
```

If you just want a `select`, then do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when depttype = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by dept) > 1
             then 'a'
             else depttype
        end) as new_depttype
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table
set depttype= case when dept in (select dept from table where depttype='a') then 'a' else depttype end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select a.dept, a.sub_dept, 
case when b.dept is not null then 'A' else dept_type end as dept_type
from aTable a
left join(
    select distinct Dept from aTable where dept_type = 'A'
) 
b on b.dept = a.dept
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use analytic functions to check whether exists the specific value in the group.

Try below query:

```
SELECT t.Dept,
       t.Sub_Dept,
       NVL(MIN(CASE WHEN t.Dept_Type = 'A'
               THEN Dept_Type END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Dept), t.Dept_Type) AS Dept_Type
  FROM table_1 t
```

Using the analytic function MIN(), you can search for the value of 'A' (if it does exist inside the group). MIN works for non-null values only, so if you don't have any 'A' in the group, the result will be NULL.

At this point, you can use NVL to choose whether to print the value found in the group or the actual dept_type of the row.